# Python JSON scraping - how can I handle missing values?

Tags: python, json

I'm pretty new to coding, so I'm learning a lot as I go. This problem got me stumped, and even though I can find several similar questions on here, I can't find one that works or has a recognizable syntax to me.

I'm trying to scrape various user data from a JSON API, og then store those values in a MySQL database I've set up.

The code seems to run fine for the most part, but some users does not have the attributes I'm trying to scrape in the JSON, and thus I'm left with Nonetype errors that I cant seem to foil.

If possible I'd like to just store "0" in the database where the json does not contain the attribute.

In the m/snippet below this works fine for users that has a job, but users without a job returns Nonetype on jobposition and apparently breaks the loop.

```
response = requests.get("URL")
json_obj = json.loads(response.text)

timer = json_obj['timestamp']
jobposition = json_obj['job']['position']

query = "INSERT INTO users (timer, jobposition) VALUES (%s, %s)"
values = (timer, jobposition)

cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute(query, values)
db.commit()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42876705/proper-way-of-handling-json-parsing-typeerror-when-element-does-not-exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use for that the get() method of the dictionary as follow

```
timer = json_obj.get('timestamp', 0)
```

0 is the default value and in case there is no 'timestamp' attribute it will return 0.
For job position, you can do

```
jobposition = json_obj['job'].get('position', 0) if 'job' in json_obj else 0
```

Comment: Damn I've been so close to this solution so many times, but somehow haven't been able to land the syntax apparently. It seems I'm not all the way there though, I had a closer look.. Some of the json attributes does not exist for all users, which can be handled the way you suggested. But as far as missing job position this is the actual json: ? "job": {
  "position": "None",
  "company_id": 0,
  "company_name": "None"``

So as you can see the attribute exists but is reported as "None" which I guess is a string instead of a null-value?

Comment: You are right when the value surrounded by " this is a string value if it will be just None it will be a None type.

Comment: Seems I'd actually misunderstood what attribute was causing the problem. The "None" strings handled just fine, I had a problem with other attributes not existing which was fixed with your code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
try:
 jobposition = json_obj['job']['position']
except:
 jobposition = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can more clearly declare the data schema using dataclasses:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

from validated_dc import ValidatedDC


@dataclass
class Job(ValidatedDC):
    name: str
    position: int = 0


@dataclass
class Workers(ValidatedDC):
    timer: int
    job: Job


input_data = {
    'timer': 123,
    'job': {'name': 'driver'}
}

workers = Workers(**input_data)

assert workers.job.position == 0
```

https://github.com/EvgeniyBurdin/validated_dc